# Replicate ProgressDialog with AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

What I am trying is to replicate the ProgressDialog since it is deprecated.
I generate a new AlertDialog in java and in front-end I've build a ProgressBar-round.
java:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashScreenActivity.this).create();
alertDialog.setMessage("Logging in...");
```

layout:

```
 <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="284dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="343dp" />
```

But I fail to understand how can I place progress bar in the AlertDialog right above the message. Also I try to make the progress bar blue and I don't see any property like that. Can anyone explain it to me please ( I have just started programming in Android Studio so I apologise for my lack of knowledge ). Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 2):

create a class MyDialog:

```
 public class MyDialog {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private View view;
    Context context;
public MyDialog(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.AlertDialog);
        view=new View(context);
    }

    public void ShowProgressDialog(Boolean cancellable) {
        try {
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress_view);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            dialog.setCancelable(cancellable);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void CancelProgressDialog() {
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

in your activity:

```
MyDialog mydialog=new MyDialog(this);

mydialog.ShowProgressDialog(false);
mydialog.CancelProgressDialog();
```

In style folder
R.style.AlertDialog:

```
   <style name="AlertDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

and in your custom progressview xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_10"
        android:background="@drawable/header_img">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_elevation_10"
            android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
            android:indeterminateTint="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:maxHeight="32dp"
            android:minHeight="32dp"
            android:minWidth="32dp" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TxtRefPicname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_elevation_10"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressBar"
        android:text="Please Wait..."
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/textsize_20"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ProgressBar in AlertDialogue's xml;

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts_study_level, null);
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
final ProgressBar progressBar= (ProgressBar) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar );
```

in `prompts_study_level.xml` You can use ProgressBar.

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin solution with androidx DialogFragment**

By using DialogFragment you don't have to resize the window every time and on every screen where you need to show the dialog, it's stable and clean solution

1. Create dialog class

```
class BaseProgressDialog : DialogFragment() {

    companion object {
        const val DIALOG_TAG = "BaseProgressDialogFragment"
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return activity?.let {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it, R.style.MainAlertDialog)
            val inflater = requireActivity().layoutInflater
            val dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_dialog, null)

            builder.setView(dialogView)
            builder.create()
        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        dialog?.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        dialog?.setCancelable(false)
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val size = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size_80dp)
        dialog?.window?.setLayout(size, size)
    }
}
```

2. Create style in your `styles.xml`

```xml
<style name="MainAlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_alert_dialog</item>
</style>
```

3. Create background for your dialog `bg_alert_dialog.xml`

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="?attr/colorSecondary"/>
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/radius_10dp" />
</shape>
```

4. Create layout for dialog `progress_dialog.xml`. You can add TextView or remove progress indicator according to your design

```xml
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_alert_dialog"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_16dp">

    <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
        android:layout_width="@dimen/size_40dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size_40dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        app:indicatorColor="?attr/colorPrimary" />

</LinearLayout>
```

5. Call dialog in the Fragment

```kotlin
private var progressDialog = BaseProgressDialog()
activity?.let {
   progressDialog.show(it.supportFragmentManager, BaseProgressDialog.DIALOG_TAG)
}
```

And this is what it will look like:

[image]